# Power BI / Power App interface is not working

Tags: powerbi, reporting, powerapps

I've build Power App report and linked it to a Power BI report. On Power Bi, I have my grid with list of data in scope for the remediation, on the right the list of records to be updated that enables the user to enter a form and populate the correct answer.

In previous reports, I could select a row in the Power Bi grid an the specific row would be selected in the Power App form. In this report, it is not working - I tried removing the Power App and re-selecting it, with no success.

Can anyone help me on this?

Removing the Power App on Power B

Answer (score 0):

Your Power App needs to have `PowerBIIntegration` for this to work.

[image]

If your app is the same app that is used in other reports, then you should have `PowerBIIntegration` already there. In this case, you need to **ensure the fields that you are adding to the visual are the same and are as expected in the app** (Hint, you can rename them in the `PowerApps Data` well.)

---

If this is a new app, or `PowerBIIntegration` is missing, then you will need to add it again. Try again to add your Power App into Power BI:

- When selecting your existing Power App in Power BI, you should see a prompt like this:
  [image]
  You must select `Go to Power Apps Studio`, wait a few seconds, and your Power App should open in edit mode in your browser. Then you should see `PowerBIIntegration` in the Tree View.
- You need to save and re-publish your app.